# How to remove HTML tags string react native - JSON?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a string variable like this:

```
{"Result":"true","Date":"","Message2":"[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Title\":\"کارت وفاداری\",\"MainText\":\"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; کارت های لویالتی کارتهايی هستند که در ازای خريد با اين کارت امتيازی برای دارنده کارت در نظر گرفته می شود.</p>\r\n\",\"Type\":\"1\"}]"}
```

I want to get content of `Message2, but I cannot:

```
    var Message2 = JSON.parse(result).Message2;
    console.log('Message2',Message2)

Message2 [{"Id":"1","Title":"کارت وفاداری","MainText":"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; کارت های لویالتی کارتهايی هستند که در ازای خريد با اين کارت امتيازی برای دارنده کارت در نظر گرفته می شود.</p>
","Type":"1"}]
```

now I should `parse` function again:

```
console.log('content of Message2',JSON.parse(Message2))
```

but it return this error message:

```
 Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 177
```

I have beed trying this but I got the same error message:

```
    console.log('content of Message2',JSON.parse(Message2.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Message2 is not a valid JSON because of `\r\n` character not because of the tag.

```
"...</p>\r\n\",\"Type\"
```